# If Else statement for new variable

Tags: r, variables, if-statement

I want to code the months into quarter and use one line of code for it. I am coding fiscal quarters. So months 4-6 is 1, months 7-9 is Quarter 2, months 10-12 is Quarter 3 and months 1-3 is Quarter 4

I have tried the ifelse statement but it gives me an error for the first part

```
ACLED$quarter<- ifelse(ACLED$month==4 & ACLED$month==5 & ACLED$month==6, 1)
```

> ```
> Error in ifelse(ACLED$month == 4 & ACLED$month == 5 & ACLED$month == 6,  : 
>   argument "no" is missing, with no default
> ```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `?ifelse`shows the required arguments for the `ifelse` function. There are three of them, and you've provided two, so one (`"no"`) is missing. There is the additional problem that no number is equal to both 5 and 4, so the first argument will resolve to a vector of all FALSE (and possibly NA) values.

Comment: You can solve this with `dplyr::case_when` or `cut`

Comment: Or using `%/%` e.g.  `c(4, 1, 2, 3)[1 + (ACLED$month - 1) %/% 3]`

Comment: That was quick thinking! How do you become more adept at R? Thanks! I will try case_when. I just need to find out if it works for 'or' condition

Comment: A month can't be 4 AND 5 AND 6. The other recommendations (with `cut` or modular arithmetic) are better, but if you proceeding with the `ifelse()` this is a place where you would want `|` for OR.

Comment: @Gregor but it can be >3 and <7 (as an alternative to `|`) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you use the dplyr package and the case_when function:

```
   library(dplyr)

   foo <- sample(1:12, 100, replace = TRUE)

   qtr <- case_when(foo %in% 4:6 ~ 1,
             foo %in% 7:9 ~ 2,
             foo %in% 10:12 ~ 3,
             foo %in% 1:3 ~ 4)
```

Comment: It still give me an error. I have the variable for month in my data already and this is the code I used: library(dplyr)
ACLED$quarter<- case_when (ACLED$month %in% 4-6 ~1,
                     ACLED$month %in% 7-9 ~2,
                     ACLED$month %in% 10-12~3,
                     ACLED$months %in% 1-3 ~4)

Comment: Error: LHS of case 1 (`ACLED$month %in% 4 - 6`) must be a logical, not double

Comment: You need to use `:`, not `-` @NM

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward with dplyr's `case_when`. I am not sure if it meets your need of "one line of code for it" though.

```
month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

df <- data.frame(month = month)

df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = case_when(
    #Quarter 1.
    month  %in% c(1,2,3) ~ 
      "First", 
    #Quarter 2.
    month  %in% c(4,5,6) ~ 
      "Second", 
    #Quarter 3.
    month  %in% c(7,8,9) ~
      "Third", 
    #Quarter 4.
    month  %in% c(10,11,12) ~ 
      "Fourth")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate the more elegant `case_when` solution that you have already received. However, `ifelse` can also do the job by using multiple `ifelse` functions with the same logic as the answer from markhogue (+1). See the documentation on `ifelse`; it needs to know what to do when criteria do not match - in this case theres three occasions where that is use another `ifelse`, and one where it is `NA`. The first argument is the match criteria (*if*), the second is what to do if the criteria are matched (*get*), and the third is what to do if the criteria are not matched (*else*).

```
set.seed(1)

df<-data.frame('mon' = sample(1:12, replace = T, size = 20))

df[,'qtr'] <- 
  ifelse(df[,'mon'] >=  1 & df[,'mon'] <=  3, 4, 
  ifelse(df[,'mon'] >=  4 & df[,'mon'] <=  6, 1, 
  ifelse(df[,'mon'] >=  7 & df[,'mon'] <=  9, 2,
  ifelse(df[,'mon'] >= 10 & df[,'mon'] <= 12, 3,  NA))))
```

Comment: My data is ACLED. What does df stand for here?

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible dataset, I just used df because I'm writing on my phone so wanted it short. Change df to ACLED and mon to month and it should work based on your code that you did give.